# powershell quest : get-qaduser -identity guid doesn't work?

Tags: powershell, quest

i start out by querying an exchange server 2003 with:

```
POSH>get-wmiobject -class Exchange_mailbox -namespace Root\MicrosoftExchangeV2 -server srv02
```

to get the users.  One of the properties available is the mailboxguid.  so for testing, I run

```
POSH> get-qaduser -identity <mailboxguid>
```

however it doesn't work.  is there something special I need to do to the mailboxguid?

thanks in advance

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Get-QADUser tries to resolve an object by one of these properties: DN, SID, GUID, UPN or Domain\UserName, mailboxguid is not one of them. That said, you can use the mailbox "MailboxDisplayName" property as the identity for Get-QADUser:

get-wmiobject -class Exchange_mailbox -namespace Root\MicrosoftExchangeV2 -server srv02 | Get-QADUser -identity {$_.MailboxDisplayName}

EDIT: Try to parse the LegacyDN WMI property if you can't use MailboxDisplayName:

get-wmiobject -class Exchange_mailbox -namespace Root\MicrosoftExchangeV2 -**computerName** srv02| Get-QADUser -identity {$*.LegacyDN.substring($*.LegacyDN.lastIndexOf("=")+1)}

btw, replace -server with -computerName, Get-WMIObject has no -server parameter.
I addition you could go the other way and not use WMI to get mailbox enabled objects, you can query AD directly:

Get-QADObject -sizeLimit 0 -ldap "(homeMDB=*)"

Comment: I was hopingthere was a more accurate way of doing this other than mailboxdisplayname because they don't always match. Is there another more accurate alternative like say getting exchange 2007 powershell to pull the same mailbox-activedirectory info on exchange 2003 servers?

Comment: when I run it against the legacydn property i get an error: invalid variable reference.  "$" was not followed by a valid variable name character.  consider using $() to delimit the name.

Comment: Phill, the post editor doesn't like the dollar+underscore combination (e.g $_), it is dropping the "_" char. Try t6o add it back, I checked it and it work.

Comment: It looks like it cleared up the errors, however its pulling the users from the wrong domain.  any ideas how to change this?  thanks in advance..

Answer (score 1):

I think the problem lies somewhere else: if you get an object (e.g. a user) from the AD through its name and look at the `ObjectGUID`, it contains a string like this:

```
(Get-QADUser -Identity myDomain\myUser).ObjectGUID 
-> CAEC64A025153143A6755E0A3DAB5C1A
```

To get the same user through its GUID, you have to specify:

```
(Get-QADUser -Identity A064ECCA-1525-4331-A675-5E0A3DAB5C1A).ObjectGUID
-> CAEC64A025153143A6755E0A3DAB5C1A
```

If you compare the GUIDs you will notice that they look somewhat similar but not the same:

```
CAEC64A0-2515-3143-A675-5E0A3DAB5C1A
A064ECCA-1525-4331-A675-5E0A3DAB5C1A
```

This problem occurs because the `System.GUID` uses a different byte-order than Active Directory to construct the GUID.

You can correct it like this (VB.NET):

```
Private Shared Function GetCorrectGuid(ByVal aWrongGuid As Guid) As Guid
  Dim myGuidString As String = aWrongGuid.ToString("N")
  Dim myWrongGuid As Char() = myGuidString.ToCharArray()
  Dim myCorrectGuid As Char() = myGuidString.ToCharArray()
  myCorrectGuid(0) = myWrongGuid(6)
  myCorrectGuid(1) = myWrongGuid(7)
  myCorrectGuid(2) = myWrongGuid(4)
  myCorrectGuid(3) = myWrongGuid(5)
  myCorrectGuid(4) = myWrongGuid(2)
  myCorrectGuid(5) = myWrongGuid(3)
  myCorrectGuid(6) = myWrongGuid(0)
  myCorrectGuid(7) = myWrongGuid(1)
  myCorrectGuid(8) = myWrongGuid(10)
  myCorrectGuid(9) = myWrongGuid(11)
  myCorrectGuid(10) = myWrongGuid(8)
  myCorrectGuid(11) = myWrongGuid(9)
  myCorrectGuid(12) = myWrongGuid(14)
  myCorrectGuid(13) = myWrongGuid(15)
  myCorrectGuid(14) = myWrongGuid(12)
  myCorrectGuid(15) = myWrongGuid(13)
  Return New Guid(New String(myCorrectGuid, 0, 32))
End Function
```

or this (C#):

```
private static Guid GetCorrectGuid(Guid aWrongGuid) {
  string myGuidString = aWrongGuid.ToString("N");
  char[] myWrongGuid = myGuidString.ToCharArray();
  char[] myCorrectGuid = myGuidString.ToCharArray();
  myCorrectGuid[0] = myWrongGuid[6];
  myCorrectGuid[1] = myWrongGuid[7];
  myCorrectGuid[2] = myWrongGuid[4];
  myCorrectGuid[3] = myWrongGuid[5];
  myCorrectGuid[4] = myWrongGuid[2];
  myCorrectGuid[5] = myWrongGuid[3];
  myCorrectGuid[6] = myWrongGuid[0];
  myCorrectGuid[7] = myWrongGuid[1];
  myCorrectGuid[8] = myWrongGuid[10];
  myCorrectGuid[9] = myWrongGuid[11];
  myCorrectGuid[10] = myWrongGuid[8];
  myCorrectGuid[11] = myWrongGuid[9];
  myCorrectGuid[12] = myWrongGuid[14];
  myCorrectGuid[13] = myWrongGuid[15];
  myCorrectGuid[14] = myWrongGuid[12];
  myCorrectGuid[15] = myWrongGuid[13];
  return new Guid(new string(myCorrectGuid, 0, 32));
}
```

And yes, I know this is not the most efficient way but I simply don't have the time to rewrite it now into a function that is based on a byte-array and that uses arraycopy. Sorry.

Hope that helps
chha